# How can I redirect users on login based on their chosen language?

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n

I'm looking to redirect users after they login.

The site is multilingual, using English and French.

I've tried using the [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module and using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but it has no options for accessing the language the user has chosen.

On the user edit page, the user can select 'English' or 'French' as their language.

I'm looking, ideally, for a simple rule condition to add, or some PHP.

None of the answers I've found so far have mentioned multilingual sites.

Thanks.

Comment: Have tried entity has field in Rules condition for User entity? Adding this condition will provide you the field in action.

Comment: What is your configuration in `admin/config/regional/language/configure` ?

Comment: Oh. It's set to URL detection only. I'm guessing that explains it.

Comment: Just to respond to @VishalPatil, I could not add the 'locale' from the User entity using "Entity has Field" in Rules.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you.

```
function custom_module_user_login(&$edit, $account){
  $base_url;
  if($account->language) {
          $redirection = $base_url.'/'.$account->language;  
  } else{
      $redirection = $base_url;
  }

  // Unless there is already a redirection going, or the user is trying to reset his password, we redirect to $redirection.

  if (!is_null($redirection) && (!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset')){
    $_GET['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
    $GLOBALS['destination'] = $redirection; // Should we use $edit['redirect'] instead..?
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `/admin/config/regional/language/configure`, you will see an option `Follow the user's language preference.`. Enable that (and optionally drag it to be at the top) and you're good to go.

Comment: Not a good answer. This would prevent the user to browse the site in other languages, when following links in the language switcher. Whatever the language code in the URL, the site would always be presented in the user language.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant and Drupal way is to modify the `$form_state['redirect']` variable.

From Drupal core code comments (in includes/form.inc):

> `$form_state['redirect']` determines where to redirect the user. This
>   can be set either to a string (the path to redirect to), or an array
>   of arguments for `drupal_goto()`.

The key part of the solution is to pass a language argument for `drupal_goto()`. First add an additional form submit handler for the login form, and modify the redirect variable in this handler. Example:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_user_login_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_login_form_submit';
}

/**
 * Switches language according to user profile.
 */
function mymodule_user_login_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  global $language;

  // Exit quickly if UI is already in correct language.
  if (!(isset($user->language) && isset($language->language) &&
    $user->language != $language->language)) {
    return;
  }

  // Verify user language exists and is enabled.
  $languages = language_list();
  if (!isset($languages[$user->language]) ||
    !$languages[$user->language]->enabled) {
    return;
  }

  // Change destination to translated equivalent, if applicable.
  if (isset($_GET['destination'])) {
    $translations = translation_path_get_translations($_GET['destination']);
    if (array_key_exists($user->language, $translations)) {
      $_GET['destination'] = $translations[$user->language];
    }
  }

  if (isset($form_state['redirect'])) {
    if (is_array($form_state['redirect'])) {
      $form_state['redirect'][1]['language'] = $languages[$user->language];
    } else {
      $form_state['redirect'] = [$form_state['redirect'], [
        'language' => $languages[$user->language],
      ]];
    }
  } else {
    $form_state['redirect'] = [sprintf('user/%d', $user->uid), [
      'language' => $languages[$user->language],
    ]];
  }
}
```

For further reading, there is a fair amount of information about this topic on this community documentation page from Drupal: [How to redirect users after login in drupal?](https://www.drupal.org/node/683696)