# redirect after login in drupal without impacting the password reset functionality

Tags: 7

The problem:

When using hook_user_login to redirect a user to the correct language this is also triggered during password reset. And the hook params do not provide a way to deal with this.

This [How can I redirect users on login based on their chosen language?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152664/how-can-i-redirect-users-on-login-based-on-their-chosen-language/220272#220272) post details multiple not working concepts.

And i can't comment cause of the silly reputation thing, while i'm a developer for over 10 years... (getting tired)

I guess the form alter is the ONLY way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook_user_login is as you'd expect for when someone goes from anonymous to authenticated. This happens by using the login form and by using a password reset link.

Having a look on Drupal's API site is always worthwhile as people have usually commented on comment occurances like this. For example on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x it has exactly what you're describing and recommends using something like:

```
if((!isset($_POST['form_id']) || $_POST['form_id'] != 'user_pass_reset')){
  //your redirect code
}
```

But also using form_alter would also be perfectly fine really as you want to target a specific action of logging in via a specific form

Comment: For example: redirect to the user's language prefix on login / pass reset.

Using HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter (MODULE_form_user_login_alter) now (with a submit callback), works perfectly.